Outlets from same breaker not working
Outlets from one breaker not working. Breaker not tripped. Only one gfci outlet which seems to be the first on line. Had microwave plugged in. Have tried resetting and nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

"Breaker not tripped." Some breakers don't look tripped when they are tripped. Did you fully turn off then turn back on the breaker? Were there two clicks when you turned the breaker back on (the switch click and the "internal mechanism tripping" click), or only one click (the switch click)?

Does anything work in the GFCI (that has been successfully reset)?

You need three things for an outlet to work.
One is the breaker is on. Two is the GFCI is on/working, and three is all the hot and neutral wires are connected and tight.
A multi-meter can help with telling where the power stops.
An older GFCI might be the first suspect, they do tend to stop working sometimes.  Loose wires are usually the second suspect, especially if the push in connections were used.
For safety turn off the breaker and check for no power before taking out outlets and/or working on the wires.


Only one gfci outlet which seems to be the first on line.

Not absolute - there are other possibilities - but the most logical situation is that the Ground Fault Circuit Interrupter (GFCI) actually detected a Ground Fault and Interrupted the Circuit.
Diagnosis should not be hard, provided you have a non-contact voltage tester (NCVT) like this Klein or a multimeter (and know how to use it) for safety:

Device Issues

Unplug the microwave and any other devices plugged in anywhere on the circuit
Small possibility that the GFCI will now work if you press RESET. If it does, plug in the devices one at a time until you find which one trips the GFCI, and that's the problem - in which case you toss the device unless it is relatively expensive (and in that case get it repaired)
Assuming the GFCI still does not work:

GFCI Issues

Turn off the breaker that you think powers the circuit
Remove the faceplate around the GFCI/receptacle
Use the NCVT to make sure there is no power (check a still-powered receptacle (which should light/beep), check this (which should show no response), check a still-powered receptacle (which should light/beep)). If there is still power then keep flipping breakers until you find the right one.
Remove the GFCI from the box but do not disconnect any wires
Turn on the breaker
Use the NCVT to verify that the incoming (line) hot wire has power. If it does not have power then STOP and ask for more help.
Turn off the breaker
Remove the outgoing (load) hot and neutral wires from the GFCI (this will be either the top or bottom pair of wires but we can't guess which it will be without more details - it will be the pair that did not have a hot wire when the breaker was on)
Turn on the breaker
Test the GFCI - RESET, see if it can power a plug-in device (carefully, because you have accessible hot wires at this time), TEST, RESET
If everything is good then the problem is downstream, most likely at one of the other receptacles, see below.
If the GFCI still does not work, can't power a device, etc. then you likely have a bad GFCI. They are much more complex than a simple receptacle and, like any electronic device, can fail over time. Replace it - typically around $20 for a decent GFCI/receptacle.

Other Receptacle Issues
A faulty receptacle or water or other stuff in a receptacle or in a receptacle box (especially if there is an outdoor receptacle on the circuit) can cause a GFCI to trip.
Attempt to figure out the sequence of receptacles. Unfortunately, except for "GFCI first" it may not be at all obvious. If you are pretty sure, do this in sequence and things will be a little easier. If not, open and disconnect all receptacles after the GFCI and then restore them one at a time.

Turn off the breaker and verify power is off at the GFCI incoming line power
Remove the faceplate from each of the other receptacles (or the first one if you are sure you know which one it is)
Verify there is no power. If there is power then you have multiple circuits involved.
If the box has any bugs, dirt, drywall dust, etc. clean it out.
Remove and label both sets of wires (unless there is only one). One set will be hot (black) and neutral (white) going back to the GFCI (or a different receptacle in sequence) and the other (if present) goes to the next receptacle.
Back at the GFCI, reattach the "load" wires
Turn on the breaker
If the GFCI trips immediately then you either have a problem with wires inside the wall (unlikely but possible) or (most likely) did not yet disconnect the next receptacle in sequence - turn off power and keep looking for another receptacle on the circuit
If the GFCI does not trip, check that the incoming hot wire for the other receptacle (or "one of the other receptacles" if you opened up more than one) has power. That identifies the next receptacle in the series
Turn off the breaker
Connect incoming hot and neutral to the receptacle. Do not connect the other set of wires.
Turn on the breaker
If the GFCI trips immediately then you have a faulty receptacle - replace it. If the GFCI does not trip then check power at the receptacle you just connected. If it is good then you are ready to move to the next receptacle. If it it is not good then turn off the breaker and check your wiring again.

Repeat for each receptacle until you have found the problem (and hopefully fixed it) or the problem simply goes away. Note that a receptacle that fits very tightly in a box, a loose connection (screw or wire nut or especially "backstab"), bugs in a box or other problems may result in a GFCI problem that simply disappears in the process of troubleshooting it. It is also possible that you may have everything "good" but when you put the receptacles back in their boxes that the problem comes back - if that happens then you may have a pinched wire or a short circuit or a screw touching the side of a metal box. In particular, a neutral screw touching a metal box will not trip a regular breaker but will trip a GFCI.
